# Why do single executable created from PyInstaller for Centos has to be ran from one folder above the executable file, i.e. the 'dist' folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I created executable in windows and centos using pyinstaller. I used --onefile attribute which creates a 'dist' folder with single executable.

```
C:\Users\myprojects\blog> pyinstaller blog.py --onefile
```

In windows, I can run executable from inside the 'dist' folder. For e.g.

```
C:\Users\myprojects\blog\dist>blog.exe
```

In Centos, I cannot run it from inside the 'dist' folder. I have to go outside dist folder to run it. For e.g.

```
C:/Users/myprojects/blog>dist/blog
```

What is the cause of this?

Comment: I think you need to use a relative pathname like `./blog` otherwise Centos will search your `$PATH` variable for `blog` which it won't find since your current directory is not part of it.

Comment: Thank you. So, what I learned is that whenever you try to run the executable, it will look at the $PATH. Let me know if I my understanding is inaccurate.

Comment: That's correct.